# ARCGIS MAP SERVICE CAN'T FIND UNICODE

Tags: sql-server, unicode, arabic, arcgis

[image: result][image: Table]
The service is not returning result when I try to search for ARABIC text. If I change the ARABIC text to English in the database then it works Fine. I use `ARCGIS` `10.1` and `SQL server 2008`. My database structure is in english only data inside it is in ARABIC. I attached screenshots for my table and the service page.

Answer (score 1):

Check the collation on the database. If you need the database collation to remain English you can try just changing the specific column collation to Arabic_CI_AS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508%28v=sql.105%29.aspx